# Adding arguments to options in Rsync

Tags: c, arguments, rsync

I am developing an application which uses the Rsync.
I have added an option for HTTP in rsync code like '-v' for "--verbose".

But now I want to make that option to take the arguments.
For that in options.c file, I have added the entry in the array of structure as,

```
static struct poptOption long_options[] = {
  /* longName, shortName, argInfo, argPtr, value, descrip, argDesc */
  {"xxxx",             'x',  xxxxxxx,   x, xxxxx, x, x},
  {"https",            'N', POPT_ARG_VAL,    &https_port, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Here the value I have provided should come in variable `https_port`. But I get the error as

```
Rsync: -N=1234: option does not take an argument
```

Where I need to make changes more to make N option to take an arguments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must parse the arg as `POPT_ARG_STRING` instead of `POPT_ARG_VAL`, and then convert it to an integer (or whatever).

See the `max-size` implementation as an example:

```
{"max-size",         0,  POPT_ARG_STRING, &max_size_arg, OPT_MAX_SIZE, 0, 0 },
```

Comment: POPT_ARG_STRING could be used, but POPT_ARG_INT checks that the value is an integer automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're exercising the modified rsync?

The man page for [`popt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popt) suggests `POPT_ARG_INT`:

```
Value               Description                       arg Type
POPT_ARG_NONE       No argument expected              int
POPT_ARG_STRING     No type checking to be performed  char *
POPT_ARG_INT        An integer argument is expected   int
POPT_ARG_LONG       A long integer is expected        long
POPT_ARG_VAL        Integer value taken from CWval    int
POPT_ARG_FLOAT      An float argument is expected     float
POPT_ARG_DOUBLE     A double argument is expected     double
```

The man page linked to has only one reference to `CWval` with no explanation of what it actually means.

Comment: Thank for your answer. One more thing is command used in rsync to invoke the remote host is like rsync --server -Dtplrze31.14Ls . /home/optimus/Desktop/.  So does it work if i add the arguments in this command as i want to send the argument of 'N' option to remote side and process

Comment: No idea; I've not looked at the source code of `rsync` itself.